# nhibernate manytomany query

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I am new to nhibernate and trying to create a query on a database with manytomany links between items and categories.

I have a database with 3 tables : items, categories and a lookup table categoryitem like this:

- categorys - primary key categoryId
- items - primary key itemId
- categoryItem - categoryId column and itemId column

I want a query returning items for a particular category and have tried this and think i am along the right lines:

```
public IList<Item> GetItemsForCategory(Category category)
        {

//detached criteria

DetachedCriteria itemIdsCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Category))     
                .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("Item.Id")))     
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Category.Id", category.Id)); 

                 criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", itemIdsCriteria));

            return criteria.List<Item>() as List<Item>;


}
```

I only have business objects for category and item.
how do i create a repository method to find items for a particular category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your classes look like this:

```
class Item
{
  // id and stuff
  IList<Category> Categories { get; private set; }
}

class Category
{
  // id and stuff
}
```

query (HQL)

```
session.CreateQuery(@"select i
from Item i
  inner join i.Categories c
where 
  c = :category")
.SetEntity("category", category)
```

Criteria

```
session
  .CreateCriteria(typeof(Item))
  .CreateCriteria("Categories", "c")
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.Id", category.Id))
```

Comment: yes it is like that. i will try that. after some searching i found this which also seems to produce the result i want but not sure if its best practise var itemIdsCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Item)).CreateCriteria("Categories").SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property("Id"))).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", category.Id)); //attach main criteria like this criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", itemIdsCriteria));